# how to get unmatched numbers in table? using R

Tags: r, random

Using the loop function in r, how can I create a function so that I have no matched numbers in each row?

```
g=sample(c(1:28, 112, replace=T))
HW=matrix(g, ncol=4, byrow=T)



HW
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   13    8   28   27
 [2,]   19   16    8   25
 [3,]   24    1    6   12
 [4,]   23   15    9   23
 [5,]    1   18   10   22
 [6,]   14   18   15   12
 [7,]   18    7   28    7
 [8,]   22   26   10   21
 [9,]    2   14   24    6
[10,]   14    4   10    8
[11,]   17   16   17   25
[12,]   21   11   19    2
[13,]   15    6    9    4
[14,]   20   19    7   14
[15,]    9    4    5    1
[16,]   11   27    5   12
[17,]   25   14   25   20
[18,]   15   27   16   26
[19,]   18   22   17    6
[20,]   12    1   20    9
[21,]    5   12   16    3
[22,]   25   12    1   17
[23,]   24    6   13   19
[24,]   16    3    1   18
[25,]    3   11    5   24
[26,]   10    9   11   23
[27,]   24   18    7    1
[28,]    5   20    4   25
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no matched numbers in each row" ? You don't want twice the same value ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct and I don't want to have a "28" in line [28] for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replicate()`

```
t(replicate(28,sample(1:28, 4, replace=F)))
```

EDIT:

This shoud work. If you wanna allow replicated numbers in the same row, just chage the `rep=FALSE` to `rep=TRUE`

```
n <- 28
out <- matrix(0,n,4)

for (i in 1:n) { 
 out[i,] <- sample((1:n)[-i],4,rep=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I also didn't want for example a 28 in line [28]?

Comment: Edited (don't know if he receives a message)